# Fix for this array? It's plotting a bunch of zeros somewhere

Tags: matlab

For some reason it's plotting red area in the figure. I'm only worried about the island that is being colored.

http://img528.imageshack.us/img528/506/2bc9e702042a46369c7631b.png

Comment: It is better to copy the code and the image to the body of your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your allocation of of `dayh99` looks like this:

```
dayh99 = zeros(length(fname),610,620);
```

And then you try to fill it with values that are out side of that range in your loop.

```
dayh99(i,240:850, 130:750) = ...
```

I think you want to begin filling at index `0` in both dimensions. This will eliminate the "red" areas in your plot.

Try this in your loop to fill `dayh00`:

```
dayh99(i,:,:) = tmp(240:850,130:750);
```